# Sharing Media Playback Between Pages with Windows Phone 7 Media Player

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-7, audio-streaming, playback

What I want to achieve:

- I want to initiate audio playback from an mp3 and/or aac HTTP stream in a WP7 application
- I want to initiate playback from a specific 'PhoneApplicationPage' instance, but still allow navigation to other pages whilst maintaining playback without any interuption - i.e. I want playback to be 'application-scope'
- I want to be able to 'seek' within my media
- I playback to continue whilst the phone is locked

What I have tried:

MediaElement:

- If the MediaElement is not owned by a page, no sound is produced when Play() is called, despite no exceptions being thrown.
- After following 'http://blog.jayway.com/2010/10/04/enable-background-audio-for-multiple-pages-in-windows-phone-7/', playback still resets between page transitions
- It also seems like a quite a hacky way of doing things...

Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaPlayer:

- Works, but "MediaPlayer.PlayPosition" is read-only, and there is no seek method.
- See post: 'http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/17318.aspx' - Apparently this is by design due to XBox constraints with Xna (?!)

Microsoft Silverlight Media Framework:

- http://smf.codeplex.com/
- My favourite option, as it seems very comprehensive
- Downloaded 'Silverlight Media Framework 2.3, WP7 specific' assemblies from:
  http://smf.codeplex.com/releases/view/57991#DownloadId=190196
- I know this is hacky, but to get something working, in the code below, the 'SMFPlayer' is static, and added to **each** page's layout on navigation.
- If the 'SMFPlayer' is not owned by a page, no sound is produced when Play() is called, despite no exceptions being thrown.
- Playback still resets between page transitions...
- Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core;
using Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media;
using Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives;

namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public static readonly SMFPlayer Player = new SMFPlayer();

        static MainPage()
        {
            Player.VolumeLevel = 1.0f;
            Player.Playlist.Add(new PlaylistItem {MediaSource = new Uri("http://smf.vertigo.com/videos/wildlife.wmv", UriKind.Absolute)});

            Player.LogLevel = LogLevel.All;
            Player.LogEntryReceived += PlayerLogEntryReceived;
        }

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Player);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(Player);
        }

        private static void PlayerLogEntryReceived(object sender, CustomEventArgs<LogEntry> e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Value.Severity + e.Value.Message + e.Value.Type);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can satisfy my requirements?
Example code?

From an architectural point of view, what I really want is a Media Service which i can send streaming URLs to without caring about which page is currently shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found a simple, but effective solution:
http://blog.reis.se/post/Enable-background-audio-for-multiple-pages-in-Windows-Phone-7-e28093-Take-2.aspx

In App.xaml:

```
<APPLICATION.RESOURCES>
    <MEDIAELEMENT x:key="GlobalMedia"></MEDIAELEMENT>
</APPLICATION.RESOURCES>
```

In App.xaml.cs:

```
public static MediaElement GlobalMediaElement
{
  get { return Current.Resources["GlobalMedia"] as MediaElement; }
}
```

In your page:

```
public partial class MyPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    MediaElement MEAudio;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
        MEAudio = App.GlobalMediaElement;
    }

    private void OnSomeEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MEAudio.xxxxx();
```

Comment: I found out that same behavior occurs with plain MediaElement on Silverlight. If it is not added to the visual tree it won't play audio. Seems adding to the app Resources instead might be a viable workaround for my case too